# How to replace an underscore with letter React Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was trying to build a hanging man game and in order to make this game, the word has been replaced by underscores like for instance `(hello) ==> _ _ _ _ _`. So every time when the player clicks on the keyButton it should replace the underscore by the matched letter.

But one important thing to keep in mind is that it should not replace the underscore for instance like when a user clicks on `e --> _ e _ _ _` and then clicks on `l --> _ _ l l _`. You see the letter e that matched was being replaced by underscore which is the case in my code. The magic happens in the **showMatchedLetter function**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { fetchButton } from '../actions';
import axios from 'axios';
import 'babel-polyfill';

const App = () => {
    const [word, setWord] = useState([]);
    const [underscore, setUnderscore] = useState([]);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const runEffect = async () => {
            const result = await axios('src/api/api.js');
            setData(result.data)
        }
        runEffect();
    }, []);

    const randomWord = () => {
        const chosenWord = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
        replaceLetter(chosenWord.word);
    }

    const replaceLetter = (string) => {
      
        let getString = string;
        setWord(getString);
        let stringToUnderScore = getString.replace(/[a-z]/gi, '_');
        setUnderscore(stringToUnderScore);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const checkLetter = (event) => {
            if(event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) {
                checkMatchLetter(word, String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase());
            }
        };

        document.addEventListener('keydown', checkLetter);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', checkLetter);
        }
    }, [word]);

    const checkMatchLetter = (word, keyButton) => {
        if(word == undefined) {
            return;
        } else {
            for(let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
                if(word[i] == keyButton) {
                    let index = i;
                    showMatchedLetter(word[i], index);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    const showMatchedLetter = (letter, index) => {
        console.log(letter, index);
        let string = word;
        string = setCharAt(string, index, letter);
        console.log(string)
    }

    const setCharAt = (string, index, letter) => {
        if(index > string.length - 1) return string;
        console.log(string)
        return underscore.substr(0, index) + letter + underscore.substr(index + 1); 
        
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{word}</p>
            <p>{underscore}</p>
            <button onClick={randomWord}></button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Where is the magic function `howMatchedLetter`?

Comment: @DennisVash I think op meant **s**howMatchedLetter

Comment: Why you using `substr` and not mutating the copy of your string? Like `string[index] = letter`?

Comment: @DennisVash That doesn't work. In JS, strings are immutable. Try it yourself: `let str = "Hello"; str[2] = "g"; console.log(str)` You'll see it's still "Hello", with no "g" in there.

Comment: Yea I meant like `string.split('')`, `string[index]=letter`, `string.join('')`

Comment: @Fresh developer You're doing the correct processing, but you're storing the result in a local variable `string` and then not using that before the end of the function. So every time you call the function, you're just starting over with the blank underscore string. You should instead set the underscores variable to to the result of that function each time if you want to keep the previous replacements intact.

Comment: Ok long conversation, but what is the answer in my case?

Comment: What even is the question ? @Freshdeveloper

Comment: question is in the title dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to approach this would be to just keep a running list of the letters that have already been guessed.

Then simply replace any letter that wasn't guessed with an underscore to get your "hidden" word each time a new letter is guessed.

The `revealOnly` function below can be implemented in any way you want, but what's important is that it takes the full word string and a list of letters to replace and then returns a new string that omits any non-guessed letters.

```js
const phrase = 'Hello World'

function revealOnly(str, guessed=[]){
  const regExpr = new RegExp(`[^${guessed.join("")}\\s]`, 'ig')
  return str.replace(regExpr, '_')
}

console.log(revealOnly(phrase, [])) // no letters guessed

console.log(revealOnly(phrase, ['e', 'l'])) // some letters guessed
```

The following is a working demo in react to demonstrate how you might use this:

```js
const { useState } = React

const App = () => {
  const [phrase, setPhrase] = useState('Hello World')
  const [guessed, setGuessed] = useState([])

  function onGuessLetter(letter){
    if(guessed.includes(letter)) return
    // add letter to guessed array
    setGuessed(prev => [...prev, letter])
  }

  function revealOnly(str, guessed=[]){
    const regExpr = new RegExp(`[^${guessed.join("")}\\s]`, 'ig')
    return str.replace(regExpr, '_')
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div> {revealOnly(phrase, guessed)} </div>
      <LetterPicker onPick={onGuessLetter} />
    </div>
  )
}

const LetterPicker = (props)=>{
  const letters = []
  for(let i = 0; i < 26; i++){
    letters.push(String.fromCharCode(97+i))
  }
  return (
   <div className={'letter-picker'}>
    {letters.map(l => <div onClick={()=>props.onPick(l)}>{l}</div>)}
   </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#root"))
```

```css
.letter-picker > div {
 display : inline-block;
 cursor : pointer;
 padding : 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Keeping a running list of letters guessed could also be useful for checking if a word has been fully revealed (although you could just check for the existence of any `_` as well). Similarly in traditional hangman fashion you can show the previously letters somewhere as well.

EDIT:

> How do I check if the entire word is guessed.

Just check if the revealed word is equal to the original phrase.

```js
const curr = revealOnly(phrase, ['h','e','l','w','o','r', 'd']
const isGuessed = curr === phrase
```

```js
const { useState } = React

const App = () => {
  const [phrase, setPhrase] = useState('Hello World')
  const [guessed, setGuessed] = useState([])

  function onGuessLetter(letter){
    if(guessed.includes(letter)) return
    // add letter to guessed array
    setGuessed(prev => [...prev, letter])
  }

  function revealOnly(str, guessed=[]){
    const regExpr = new RegExp(`[^${guessed.join("")}\\s]`, 'ig')
    return str.replace(regExpr, '_')
  }
  
  const curr = revealOnly(phrase, guessed)
  const isGuessed = curr === phrase

  return (
    <div>
      <div> {curr} </div>
      <div>Gussed: {isGuessed.toString()} </div>
      <LetterPicker onPick={onGuessLetter} />
    </div>
  )
}

const LetterPicker = (props)=>{
  const letters = []
  for(let i = 0; i < 26; i++){
    letters.push(String.fromCharCode(97+i))
  }
  return (
   <div className={'letter-picker'}>
    {letters.map(l => <div onClick={()=>props.onPick(l)}>{l}</div>)}
   </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#root"))
```

```css
.letter-picker > div {
 display : inline-block;
 cursor : pointer;
 padding : 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Nice this is exactly the solution I was looking for! One more question, how do I check if all the entire word are guested.